# How to get all objects in a window – with their settings

Tags: python, tkinter

the idea is to get informations of all Buttons, Labels, Input fields ... treeviews of a given window.
With this info it would be possible to Switch off all Buttons or hide all Input fields where the Name starts with "xx". The best way to visualize the idea would be a treeview like:

```
\window
     \Frame1
         \button1(Name,x,y ...)
         \button2(..)
      \Frame2
```

until now I found the really last part of the info

```
    from tkinter import Button
    b = Button()
    for k in b.configure().keys():
            print (k, ':', b.cget(k))

    from tkinter import Listbox
    li = Listbox()
    for k in li.configure().keys():
            print (k, ':', li.cget(k))
```

but how to do a Iteration over all Elements of a window?
I didn't find something like 
          typeof(button) == true ...
          or typeof(object) -> Button ...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `widget.winfo_children()` to get a list of all widgets that are direct descendants of `widget`.

Given a reference to a widget, you can call `widget.keys()` to get a list of all configurable options for a widget.  You can get the value with the `cget` method (eg: `widget.cget("background")`).

You can get the internal tkinter type or class of a widget with the `winfo_class` widget (eg: `widget.winfo_class()`).

Comment: thanks. I will try to do it with your hints. But maybe I must come back to you

Comment: this is my Code:
        for wc in root.winfo_children():
            print("class():   ",wc.winfo_class())
            print("parent():  ",wc.winfo_parent())
            print("name():    ",str(wc.winfo_name()))
            print("full name of object:",str(wc))
            print("wc.winfo_id():      ",wc.winfo_id())
            for wck in wc.configure().keys():
                print(wck, ":", wc.cget(wck))
               
Looks fine but i still need the real Name of the widget

Comment: @bertil: what do you mean by "real name"? If you're wanting to get the name of the variable that points to the widget, you can't get that information.  You could easily have more than one variable (or no variable at all) associated with a widget. That being said, you can assign a name to a widget with the `name` parameter, and that name is what `winfo_name` will return (eg: `Label(root, name='my label')`

Comment: in your example 'my label' is what i call the real Name. In my Code(sorry for the Format) you see the parent, which is '.' And you see the full Name 'print("full name of object:",str(wc)) '  which is '.4747466' for example. But I Need 'my label'. I can NOT come from the internal id back to the real Name.